# Масштабирование элементов от размера экрана xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Какие есть возможности масштабирования элементов xaml в зависимости от размера экрана? 
Например, экран по дефолту имеет длину 400 пикселей,элементы на 4 дюймовом и на 4,5 дюймовом экранах смотрятся по разному, есть ли какая то возможность настроить размер элемента в процентах от размера экрана?
Длина toggle в обоих случаях равна 360.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [ViewBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Внутри viewbox все элементы прописывать?

Comment: ViewBox растягивает свой контент. Попробуйте! Возможно, вам нужен будет он не везде, а только на части приложения.